# how to call "CALL ACTION" inLoop in SPD workflow2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I'm trying to call ***call action*** in Loop in shrepoint2013 workflow.
in ***call action*** am calling  ***REST API*** and passing one variable which holds dynamic value according to ***LOOP's iteration*** ,when I have ***call action*** inside Loop then loop iterates only first item value successfully and  rest of the items are not get iterated but loop is got properly execute according to it's condition(i.e number of iterations)
        when am calling the ***call action*** after passing variable value to ***REST API*** am putting some of it's variables in workflow's log,into and those are **Response**(i.e json result variable) and **Response Code** which holds status of **call action** ,at the first iteration the Response variables log is like {"d":{"CopyTo":null}} as am copying document and Response Code variables value is OK,but from second iteration and onwards the Response variable shows error as  **{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"url\u000d\u000aParameter name: Specified value is not supported for the url parameter."}}}** and **Response Code** variable in History log shows **bad request** status